# Compare two folders recursively and save repeated files

Tags: windows, iis, powershell, deployment

I'm trying to do something pretty weird. Any alternative solution could be analyzed but the process where I'm working is very difficult to change.

I have a folder to deploy in an IIS web server. This folder can contain any file such as dll, asmx, web.config, .exe, etc. We have a bat script that performs a full backup but a simple file deploy can last for an hour because of this.

I want some utility or to make a powershell script to compare the folder to deploy with the destination folder, and only backup the files (or folder) that has the same files on the first folder. This has to be done recursively and it also has to preserve folder structure in the destination server.

Edit: I'm currently working on a powershell script that will go like this (i'm definitely not a powershell expert):

```
Compare-Object $d1 $d2 | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -ne "=>" -and $_.InputObject -ne "*.ok*" -and $_.InputObject -ne "*.bat*" }
```

Any help or recommendation would be appreciated!
Regards

Comment: Do you mean that you want to backup all files in the source folder tree, but ignore any extra files that don't already exist in the target folder tree?  What are the two paths?

Comment: I want to backup all the files in the target folder tree that will be replaced by files in the source folder. I know this files will be replaced because they have the same names in the source folder.

Example:
 - source: c:\deploy\app\crm.exe
 - dest: c:\webapp\app\crm.exe
   c:\webapp\app\pay.exe
   
(make backup only of crm.exe in destination)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to maintain file structure using compare-object... I got bored so here you go.

```
$sPath = "C:\test\"
$dPath = "C:\test2\"
$src = gci -recurse $sPath
$dest = gci -recurse $dPath
$src | % { 
    foreach($item in $dest) {
        $t1 =  ($item.FullName).trimStart($dpath)
        $t2 =  ($_.FullName).trimStart($sPath)
        if($t1 -eq $t2) {copy-item $item.FullName $_.FullName -Force}
    }
}
```

Just set $spath to src directory and $dPath to your deployment directory, and let her rip.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cole9350. I won't be using it though, because of performance issues. It's faster for me to make a full backup of the destination folder because it is pretty large.

Comment: Ok understandable. Unfortunately I do not see a way to do it to get efficiency better than O(n^2).. There definitely is a way but too complex for me to code for you :D

Comment: Cool. Not sure that will speed up the process but I guess it's worth a shot. Seems like the problem lies within the deployment procedure.